# How to perform %let on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, rstudio

I have a code in SAS and in it a relate the periods of time in the `%LET` macro and i use it like this:

```
%let month_reference = feb19

    proc sql;
    create table sales_v01 as select
    *
    from  sales_&month_reference 
    where sales_code = 99
;run;
```

I am using the `%LET` because there are many other tables being used that need to have this part of the code updated monthly, so updating them manually would be too costly for me.

However I am changing from SAS to RStudio I am programing in SQL in the RStudio. I am wondering then how to perform the `%LET` in this new system.

I now have something like

```
SALES <- 
"CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE SALES_V01 AS SELECT
*
FROM SALES_FEB19 
WHERE SALES_CODE = 99"
```

How can i replace the `FEB19` with a standardized statement that requires to be changed only in one part of the code and not many times over all the places it is used? How can i make that reference IN RStudio programming in SQL?

Comment: If you are using Rstudio then use R code to generate the string that contains the SQL statement you want to run.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance of R, but I'm guessing the %let declares a re-usable block of code - i.e. a function or macro which you can call from other code? In SQL Server the equivalent is going to be either a Stored Procedure or a Function, depending on exactly how you want to use it. You can read about both the Microsoft Docs (and many other places) and decide which might be best in your situation.

Comment: Why do you use separate tables per month in the first place? They don't improve performance. You don't need any kind of partitioning unless you have *several* millions of rows. SQL Server provides partitioning natively. Since SQL Server 2016 SP1 it's available in all editions, even Express and LocalDB.

Comment: @ADyson It works a like that, yes. When i state the %let i can use the month_reference many times in my code and whenever it is mentioned the program will understand that it must be read as feb19. Then i only need to change the date to mar19 in the %let and all the other month_reference will be uptaded automatically. My issue is that, when writing SQL inside RStudio, i need to declare what i am doing, hence the SALES <- "etc", and inside the quotes it will not read any other statements that i might come to do. If i write month_reference <- feb19 outside quotes, it doesn't make the reference

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am not sure if this is relevant, but this is was only an example. I am making several calculations, merging tables, filtering values etc along the whole process. From what i understand i cannot have a PROC SQL filter my database for something that i have calculated in the same procedure. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using R to generate the SQL code to pass to the database then just use normal R string manipulation.

```
> month_reference <- "feb19"
> base_code <- "create table sales_v01 as select * from  sales_"
> want_code <- paste(base_code,month_reference,sep="")
> want_code
[1] "create table sales_v01 as select * from  sales_feb19"
>
```

Comment: If I need to end the SQL part with only the reference pending, then how do I do when i apply filter-like code, like `from sales_feb19 where sales_code = 99`?

Comment: Huh? The same way you would change the string "fred" to the string "fred where sales_code = 99".  Either include the leading space in the string to *paste* or set the sep= value to include a space.  If you want to use the `paste()` function look up how it works.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!